# Google Advanced News Search

Tags: search, google-news

I would like to Google News Search that searches for several terms and eliminates the duplicates.

Google provides several Booleans, but none quite do what I'm after.

Take :: `Fiscal cliff, US debt, UK bank exposure, IMF`

I want to see results for all of these in the news feed for the past 24 hours, but each searched as if it had been done individually.

Using the `"Fiscal cliff" OR "US debt"` etc... would do this, but would search for the exact phrase.

Using `Fiscal cliff OR US debt` etc... also searches for Fiscal debt and US cliff.

I want each of these to work like they would if I searched for them individually giving me all results for each term in the last 24 hours.

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses seem to do the trick. I don't see the exact result count in Google News, but I see it in the plain old Google :

```
"Fiscal cliff" OR "US debt"
```

About 82,200,000 results

```
(Fiscal cliff) OR (US debt)
```

About 358,000,000 results

Comment: Limit it to 24 hours and you will see fewer results with the keywords combined, than each one has separately. Something isn't right here